# Detect when SqlDataAdapter fill method completes

Tags: datatable, fill, sqldataadapter

I have a global `SqlDataAdapter` that serves multiples SqlCommand. The problem is sometimes the `SqlDataAdapter` fill method raise an error saying

`There is already an open DataReader associated with this Command...`

I'm wondering if exists some way to know when the fill method still executing?

I'd heard that SqlDataAdapter use a `DataReader` internally.

Can get that `DataReader`?

Answer (score 0):

*"I have a global SqlDataAdapter"* - that's your mistake. Do away with that notion and make a DataAdapter whenever you want to use one. Put it in a `using` statement so you don't forget to Dispose of it.

Also, if you're caching connections and opening closing them manually, don't do that either - just give the adapter (that you make on the spot) an SQL string and a connection string and let it make the connection and command objects. The only time you might want to create a connection and open it yourself is if you have a lot of operations to perform in sequence using different adapters, perhaps as part of a transaction. Don't forget that opening and closing a connection is not necessarily making a TCP connection to the database (slow) - it's leasing and returning a currently connected and usable connection from a pool of connections and is a trivial operation

The more you try and micromanage this, the worse it will get and trying to jiggle around, detecting this and waiting for that is a) unnecessary, b) a hacky mess to try and work around the corner you've painted yourself into , c) going to give a substandard UI experience.

Comment: I'd declared a local SqlDataAdapter but the error raise anyway

Comment: Yes, i set the SqlDataAdapter SelectCommand property but with a SqlDataAdapter declared inside a function.

Comment: And the error says "this command already has an open datareader"...

Comment: So, circling back to the bit where I mentioned "make a new data adapter, and give it an SQL string and a connection string and let it make the command and connection" - if you do that then you don't get the same command being used in multiple places and already having an open datareader

Comment: Seems to me that the error message is incorrect because i'm using distinct command objects. Maybe the connection does not support multiples commands at the same time.